# My app does not seem to find my button from the UI file

Tags: qt

What i did:

create a project,

edited the ui file with the designer tool,

ran the project, everything is ok

tried to add to my cppfile:

```
connect( pushButton_bracketBegin, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( pushButton_bracketBeginAction() ) );
```

but i get the error "‘pushButton_bracketBegin’ was not declared in this scope". this is my first project in qt and it should be fairly simple i guess (but yet out of my grasp ) :) appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the button is part of the ui object, so the correct way to  get it is ui->buttonName :D